# Why is my character still low poly and slightly distorted after baking?

Tags: modifiers, uv, baking, retopology

I have been trying to successfully bake my character from a high poly sculpt... the bake settings are: cycles render engine, normal bake type (then diffuse after), with a ray distance set to 0.02m.

[image: low poly and high poly mesh before baking]

[image: low poly and high poly mesh after baking]

Here is the cavity map for the diffuse bake too:

[image: cavity map]

Any advice welcome! I applied a few modifiers previously too, including a multiresolution modifier, shrink wrap and mirror.

Comment: maybe try to increase the Extrusion value? I think Maximum Ray Distance is the length of the ray, not sure if it's useful here...

Comment: This tutorial might be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQPjIGncXcM&ab_channel=Jayanam

Comment: @moonboots this worked btw! Thank you so much. :D

Answer (score 1):

Increase the *Extrusion* value and set the *Maximum Ray Distance* to 0